# Indicator of the acoustic level in near field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, measurements

Usually in acoustics, it is assumed that what we hear is the acoustic pressure. In far field - when the distance to the source is larger than the size of the source and than the wavelength - one has $p = \rho c v$ with $p$ the acoustic pressure, $\rho$ the density, $c$ the sound velocity and $v$ the speed of the air. So a good measure of the acoustic power intensity is $I = \overline{pv}$ and the acoustic power is $P = \int_{source} dS \ I(\mathbf{r})$.

Now, let us consider that a thin plate - like a sound board - is vibrating and radiating sound. Close to this plate, things are different.

[image]

- "Active control of vibration", Fuller, Christopher C and Elliott, Sharon and Nelson, Philip A

> Although the sound power radiated by the panel usefully
>   quantifies the far-field pressure it generates, high levels of
>   vibration in weakly radiated modes can give rise to signifi-
>   cant pressure levels in the near field of the panel. It has been
>   shown that the total kinetic energy of a panel provides a
>   better measure of near-field pressure than radiated sound
>   power, (11) and so if there is any possibility that listeners may
>   be in close proximity to the panel, as well as being further
>   away, then both of these criteria are important for active
>   structural acoustic control.

- "*Active vibroacoustic control with multiple local feedback loops", Stephen J Elliott, Paolo Gardonio, and Michael J. Brennan*

Reference (11) in the above excerpt refers to

- M.E. Johnson and S.J. Elliott, ‘‘Active control of sound radiation using volume velocity cancellation,’’ J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 98, 2174 –2186, 1995.

The authors of this paper consider kinetic energy to be a good indicator, but they do not detail why.

Indeed, in near field - within a few wavelength to the panel - one has not $p(\mathbf{r}) \propto v(\mathbf{r})$ but

- $v(\mathbf{r}) = \dot w(\mathbf{r})$ where $w$ is the tangential displacement of the plate
- $p(\mathbf{r}) = \int_{plate} dS \ \frac{j \omega \dot{w} (\mathbf{r_s})e^{-j k |\mathbf{r - r_s}|}}{2 \pi |\mathbf{r - r_s}|}$

I think that in the near field, $\int_{plate} p^2$ must resemble to the kinetic energy $\int_{plate} v^2$, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I am a little confused by a few things.  You state that $P \propto v$ so would it not follow that $P^{2} \propto v^{2}$?  I am also confused about what you call "near field."  Is not the near field the region where you are within a few wavelengths of the source, i.e., near this panel (by the way, what are these panels to which you refer)?

Comment: "... one has not p ~ v".  This is the issue.  However I am also confused in that it seems that the OP convolves plate motion with fluid motion.  At the surface a BC may constrain the movement but even within a few wavelengths away the full system of fluid equations (or the linearized wave equation) should hold.  I think too many disparate sources are being referenced, perhaps out of context.

Comment: Yes I don't really know until which distance the fluid speed can be considered the same as the plate's speed. What I really want to understand is the quote. I put the other sources to explain the problem and what I tried to do.

Comment: @Cabirto, which quote are you focused on?  The one with a pink-ish background?

Comment: Yes, I am focused on the quote in pink-ish background.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already quoted, the **active** (or else propagating) intensity is not very indicative of the sound pressure (or for that reason, the particle velocity) at the near field. This is due to the fact that the particle velocity $u$ and the sound pressure $p$ are **not** in phase.

From the formulation of a "simple" point source one gets for pressure and particle velocity

$$ p \left( r , t \right) = \frac{j \omega \rho Q}{4 \pi r} e^{j \left(\omega t - k r \right)} \tag{1} \label{pressure} $$

$$ u \left( r , t \right) = \frac{j k Q}{4 \pi r} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{j k r} \right) e^{j \left(\omega t - k r \right)} = \frac{p \left( r, t  \right)}{\rho c} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{j k r} \right) \tag{2} \label{velocity} $$

where $j$ is the imaginary unit for which $j^{2} = -1$ holds true, $\omega = 2 \pi f$ with $f$ the temporal frequency is the radial frequency, $\rho$ the medium density, $Q$ is the "strength" of the source (actually is the volume velocity of the radially vibrating sphere), $k = \frac{\omega}{c} = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ is the wavenumber and $c$ is the speed of sound (magnitude of group velocity) and $\lambda$ is the wavelength for which $\lambda = \frac{c}{f}$ holds. Finally, $r$ denotes the distance from the source since the formulation is in spherical coordinates.

From equations \eqref{velocity} we see that the particle velocity has a component which is in-phase with the pressure and a component which is in quadrature (the $\frac{p \left( r, t \right)}{j k r \rho c}$ part) which asymptotically reaches $0$ with increasing distance. This part is the non-propagating part of the intensity, usually termed **reactive intensity**. It has similar characteristics to the reactive power in (power) electronics and does not contribute to the propagating acoustic energy. This is actually, what your second equations depicts.

Of course, this formulation is about a point source, but in general, similar behaviour is exhibited by all real sources. The non-propagating "waves" (or components of the total wave intensity) are most often termed **evanescent waves**.

The resulting wavefield, assuming linear acoustics (this means that the wave amplitudes should not be very large), must satisfy the Helmholtz equation

$$ \nabla^{2} p \left( x, y, z, \omega \right) + k^{2} p \left( x, y, z, \omega \right) = 0 \tag{3} \label{helmholtz} $$

Assuming complex exponential solutions to the Helmholtz equation the resulting solution is

$$ p \left(x, y, z, \omega \right) = \hat{p} \left( \omega \right) e^{-j \left( k_{x} x + k_{y} y + k_{z} z \right)} \tag{4} \label{solution} $$

which holds if $k^{2} = k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} + k_{z}^{2}$, which is the *dispersion relation* that is necessary for this solution.

Assuming propagation in the $z$ direction, as in the graph you provided, we can solve for $k_{z}^{2}$ from equation \eqref{solution} to get

$$ k_{z}^{2} = k^{2} - k_{x}^{2} - k_{y}^{2} \tag{5} \label{z-wavenumber} $$

From equation \eqref{z-wavenumber} we see that there are four possible solutions to this equation, namely

$$ k_{y} = \begin{cases}
           \pm \sqrt{k^{2} - k_{x}^{2} - k_{y}^{2}} & k^{2} \geq k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} \\
           \pm j \sqrt{k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} - k^{2}} & k^{2} \leq k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} \end{cases} \tag{6} \label{wavenumber-solutions} $$

So, the first part of the equation (first two solutions) represents a propagating wave which contributes to the **active intensity**, while the second part (complex solutions) represent the evanescent waves, which constitute the evanescent waves that do not propagate outwards. Of course, the total solution to equation \eqref{helmholtz}, with the help of equations \eqref{solution} and \eqref{wavenumber-solutions} will be

$$ p \left(x, y, z, \omega \right) = \hat{p} \left( \omega \right) e^{\pm \sqrt{k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2} - k^{2}}} e^{-j k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2}} \tag{7} \label{complete-solution} $$

where for the above equation in the first exponential, which is purely real, the positive exponent results in $p\left(x, y, z, \omega \right) = \infty$ for $z \rightarrow + \infty$, which is non-physical and is dropped/rejected.

All this discussion has gone towards justifying the inability of the propagating **active intensity** to accurately describe the wavefield close to the source. The following *.gif* is an attempt to show exactly that (source: Daniel A. Russell, The Pennsylvania State University)

[image]

At the above *.gif* you can see that the neighbouring areas at the vicinity of the red particle have opposite phase resulting in the oscillation of the particle back and forth. In essence, the energy is "stored" in the system and does not propagate outwards. Nevertheless, the particle is moving the collective move of all the particles in this vicinity does indeed create pressure compressions and rarefactions in an oscillatory manner. This is exactly the evanescent wave we calculated above.

Since the pressure measured in a distance is not characteristic of the wave-patterns produced by the evanescent waves (since they do not propagate), another quantity should be used instead. From joint inspection of the *.gif* presented above and use of the equation for the intensity ($I = p u$), I believe that particle velocity is the most intuitive quantity to use. Of course, this is related to the kinetic energy of the system, especially if we assume that very close to the boundary, the particle velocity of the air particles is that of the boundary.

Making use of the second equation you provided (replicating here for completeness)

$$ p \left( \mathbf{r} \right) = \int_{plate} dS \ \frac{j \omega \dot{w} \left( \mathbf{r_s} \right) e^{-j k \left| \mathbf{r - r_s} \right|}}{2 \pi \left| \mathbf{r - r_s} \right|} \tag{8} \label{nearfield-pressure} $$

The result of equation \eqref{nearfield-pressure} shows that indeed the sound pressure in the nearfield is related to the particle velocity of the soundfield ($\dot{w}$). Furthermore, from the above equation you can see that if one knows the particle velocity can very well calculate the pressure at some distance from the source. For the researchers of the articles you cited, consistent minimisation of the pressure is the goal of their active noise control approach. Thus, by minimising the particle velocity they can minimise the pressure in the nearfield and by that, minimise the intensity too, since minimisation of both constituents of the intensity will result in its minimisation too. This would achieve energy minimisation in the nearfield.